# How can I export only the CSS used in a site? (Without: dust-me-spider, firebug)

Tags: css, export

I have made a project and I want to export only the CSS which has been used in the project or page. I have tried, dust-me-spider and firebug, but these add-ons grab all the CSS of the project! I need to grab only the CSS which has been used and export it to another CSS file. Does any program exist for such a reason?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please try to elaborate and put some details of what you have done?

Comment: I want to export only the usage css from my web site. You now an program to grab only the usage css and then can export it?